# An attempt on making REST API for nested attribute using Restivus

Tags: mongodb, api, rest, meteor

So, I'm trying to show how Restivus API works and Meteor is nice to my colleagues. :)

I've made a simple blog app at http://askar-blog.meteor.com/ (thanks to DiscoverMeteor book).
My repo https://github.com/tenzan/blog

(I'm reading https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus#restivus)

I have three collections:

1. `users`
2. `posts`
3. `comments`

So, `post` has many `comments`. Usually, we used to have `comments` as a nested documents inside of a `post`, but from the Meteor's nature these two attributes are split up into different collections.

I want to implement a REST API, so that I can access (including `CRUD` operations) `posts` and `collections` in the way:

`http://example.com/api/posts` - all `posts`

`http://example.com/api/posts/post_id` - a specific `post`

`http://example.com/api/posts/post_id/comments` - all `comments` that belongs to a given `post`

`http://example.com/api/posts/post_id/comments/comment_id` - a specific `comment` that belongs to a given `post`

If you have a look at my repo, you will see there're `posts.js` and `comments.js` under `lib/collections`.

As I understood, to enable REST API, I will need the following snippet in the `posts.js`:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    // Global API configuration
    var Api = new Restivus({
        useDefaultAuth: true,
        prettyJson: true
    });

    // Generates: GET, POST on /api/post and GET, PUT, DELETE on
    // /api/items/:id for the Posts collection
    Api.addCollection(Posts);

    // Generates: POST on /api/users and GET, DELETE /api/users/:id for
    // Meteor.users collection
    Api.addCollection(Meteor.users, {
        excludedEndpoints: ['getAll', 'put'],
        routeOptions: {
            authRequired: true
        },
        endpoints: {
            post: {
                authRequired: false
            },
            delete: {
                roleRequired: 'admin'
            }
        }
    });
```

As you see, I've added `Api.addCollection(Posts);` and I've confirmed I can access all `posts` or a specific one.

**My questions:**

1- How can I setup API to access `comments` for their parent `post`?

2 - Will I have to have to following code to access `posts` ? I'm asking because, I'm already able to access them as I have `Api.addCollection(Posts);` :

```
Maps to: /api/posts/:id
    Api.addRoute('posts/:id', {authRequired: true}, {
        get: function () {
            return Posts.findOne(this.urlParams.id);
        },
        delete: {
            roleRequired: ['author', 'admin'],
            action: function () {
                if (Articles.remove(this.urlParams.id)) {
                    return {status: 'success', data: {message: 'Post removed'}};
                }
                return {
                    statusCode: 404,
                    body: {status: 'fail', message: 'Post not found'}
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

I apologise, I got confused myself trying to figure out the correct way of making a REST API.

Please feel free to add anything important on this regard I have missed here.

Answer (score 0):

I've discussed with the author of the package

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/issues/128

The feature is being developed

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus/issues/70